# Outputting Sprout Form from a matrix field

Tags: plugin-sproutforms

I'm using Sprout Forms to handle email forms on a website. Hardcoding a template with the code: `{{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm('contactForm') }}` works fine like in the docs.

But I have a Matrix field to build the page content so I'd like to add a new field type to that I can select which form to display. There is a Matrix field type 'sprout forms' which lets me select the form fine in the CMS.

My question is how do I now display the form in the template. I can't see any documentation on how to do this?

I've tried things like `{{ block.customForm.displayForm() }}` but with no luck.

Has anyone tried this before?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, you'll likely want to use:

```
{% for block in entry.pageBody %}
    {% if block.type == 'form' %}
        {{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm(block.form.first.handle) }}
    {% endif %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: Perfect. This worked. In my case I used:
{{ craft.sproutForms.displayForm(block.customForm.first.handle) }}

customForm being the name of the field in matrix.

Many thanks